# MYSQL return a single row query with a format

Tags: mysql, procedures

I got this procedure :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `countRows`(IN v varchar(30))
BEGIN
   SET @t1 =CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  ",V);
   PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
   EXECUTE stmt3;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And I want this to return the query in this format : "The table X contains Y Rows" I tried to use the concat function but it just don't work for me.

Some tips? Thanks

Comment: I edit the question, sorry if it wasn't clear enought.

Comment: Well you shouldn't have taken out part of your query. The question is clear, what I meant is: are you getting an error? Does it return incorrect results? I just want to understand how/why it isn't doing what you need it to.

Comment: The syntax of the old procedure was fine but When I call the procedure and give by parameters the name of the table that I wanted it just didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work by using a subquery. I couldn't find any way to do the concat and count search at the same time, but by wrapping the count into a subquery and then using that value in the select clause I was able to return the expected results. Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT("The table contains ", tmp.numRows, " rows.")
FROM(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS numRows
  FROM myTable) tmp;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c29d/9) example of the query by itself, not as a prepared statement.

Comment: This works and is what I want but I don't know how to impement it to my procedure, some help?

Comment: @Edw4rd I don't use a lot of stored procedures, but I will tinker with it when I can. Let me know if you have any more trouble.